# Python, Pandas: Filter dataframe to a subset and update this subset in place

Tags: python, pandas, in-place

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like:

```
cleanText.head()
    source      word    count
0   twain_ess            988
1   twain_ess   works    139
2   twain_ess   short    139
3   twain_ess   complete 139
4   twain_ess   would    98
5   twain_ess   push     94
```

And a dictionary that contains the total word count for each source:

```
titles
{'orw_ess': 1729, 'orw_novel': 15534, 'twain_ess': 7680, 'twain_novel': 60004}
```

My goal is to normalize the word counts for each source by the total number of words in that source, i.e. turn them into a percentage. This seems like it should be trivial but python seems to make it very difficult (if anyone could explain the rules for inplace operations to me that would be great).

The caveat comes from needing to filter the entries in `cleanText` to just those from a single source, and then I attempt to inplace divide the counts for this subset by the value in the dictionary.

```
# Adjust total word counts and normalize
for key, value in titles.items():

    # This corrects the total words for overcounting the '' entries
    overcounted= cleanText[cleanText.iloc[:,0]== key].iloc[0,2]
    titles[key]= titles[key]-overcounted

    # This is where I divide by total words, however it does not save inplace, or at all for that matter
    cleanText[cleanText.iloc[:,0]== key].iloc[:,2]= cleanText[cleanText.iloc[:,0]== key]['count']/titles[key]
```

If anyone could explain how to alter this division statement so that the output is actually saved in the original column that would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand Correctly:

```
cleanText['count']/cleanText['source'].map(titles)
```

Which gives you:

```
0    0.128646
1    0.018099
2    0.018099
3    0.018099
4    0.012760
5    0.012240
dtype: float64
```

To re-assign these percentage values into your `count` column, use:

```
cleanText['count'] = cleanText['count']/cleanText['source'].map(titles)
```

Comment: Are you able to elaborate on this? For instance, why would I want to divide by `cleanText['source']` as this is not a numeric value, but a string? Or does this simply partition the data into groups of the same source?

Does `.map` perform division?

Thanks

Comment: `cleanText['source'].map(titles)` creates a column of your numeric values from `titles`. For instance, it would give you `7680` for `twain_ess `, and `60004` for `twain_novel`. Then, the division is just done by the `/` operator

Comment: Thank you sacul, that does seem to work for performing the operation. However, it doesn't resolve my assignment issue. How could this be used to save into the appropriate row of `cleanText['count']` such that my df then contains only the percentage values?